# Make View behind an overlapping View to respond to Tap event

Tags: android, events, android-view

I have two `ImageView`s, `iv1` and `iv2`, where `iv2` overlaps on the `iv1` with `20dp`.

Now, if I tap exactly in the region where `iv1` is visible, it responds to event, but if I set `iv2`'s visibility to `GONE` or `INVISIBLE` and also make it's `setEnabled(false)`, I can see `iv1` completely, but still only partial of its region (which was visible behind `iv2`) is responsive to tap events.

How can I make complete ImageView to be tap responsive if overlapping view is disabled or is invisible?

Comment: Are you sure you have set the imageview to "gone", not to "invisible"?

Comment: @Christine: I actually tried both one-by-one but none of them worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's happening because iv2 is in front of iv1. Try calling `iv1.bringToFront();`. That will place iv1 in front of iv2 and it's full area becomes tap responsive.

And if later you want to change visibility of iv2 you'll have to call `iv2.bringToFront();` to make things like they were before setting iv2 invisible.

If you want to place iv1 in front of iv2 from the beginning you have to put it's definition in xml file after iv2's. The views will be drawn in the order of their appearance in layout xml file. So the first view is on the bottom, the last is on the top.

Comment: Can you expand on why he should use this function and what it does?  This is a learning site and answers need more explanations.